# Multi user messaging schema design

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database for a new project. I faced some trouble. In my design i have two tables student, faculty. I want to store their messages into message table.

1.student
2.faculty
3.Message

[image: Multi user messaging schema design]

> Blue color line defines which is the foreign key of user table. Blue color selected column are the foreign key of user table.

It basically consists of secure messaging system with those abilities :

> *Every student can send message each others student.
>
> *Every faculty can send message each others faculty.
>
> *student and faculty both can send message each others.

1.I am having difficulties how to implement relationship between student, faculty and message table.

2.Keep them separate in two table is right?? or how I implement it??

3.please Suggest me how improve design and their relationship not SQL code.

> My complete design is here [University Database Design.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691064/university-database-design)

Comment: So, everyone can send messages to everyone else?  I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @paqogomez I didn't implement any relationship here, pls check the screen short.

Comment: I still dont understand, are you looking for a sql query to show messages for each user? Are you wanting to know which constraints to put on the table? What are your requirements?

Comment: I am not looking for sql query. I have two table Student and faculty. I want to store their messages into Message table. How to improve my design?

Comment: message table should contain sender id and receiver id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion,

1. add a new table call user, take all the similar column from faculty and student put in that.
2. point your foreign key for table faculty and student. Here will be the relationship that you looking at.
3. add another column receiver in your message table referring to uid, your message table must have sender and receiver right? else you won't know the message is for who.
4. point your foreign key for user table and message table, sender/receiver vs uid. Here is another relationship that you trying to get.
5. take a look on your notification and message column in table faculty, not sure they still needed so I just remain it.

Happy programming.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (
>                 uid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
>                 first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>                 last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>                 nick_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>                 genere VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
>                 email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>                 facebook VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>                 mobile INT NOT NULL,
>                 image VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>                 cv VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 PRIMARY KEY (uid)
> );
>
>
>
> CREATE TABLE Message (
>                 Message_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
>                 sender VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 receiver VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 text VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 send_date_time DATE NOT NULL,
>                 PRIMARY KEY (Message_id)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE faculty (
>                 fid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
>                 designation VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>                 notification VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 message VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>                 PRIMARY KEY (fid)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE student (
>                 sid VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
>                 batch TINYINT NOT NULL,
>                 cgpa DOUBLE PRECISIONS NOT NULL,
>                 PRIMARY KEY (sid)
> );
> ```

Comment: check my 2, 4, over there I pointed which column to use, syntax wise you should be able to do it urself right ?

Comment: I didn't understand what kinds of relation you mean. In step 2 uid foreign key for table faculty and student???

Comment: 2.point your foreign key for table faculty and student. Here will be the relationship that you looking at. All student/faculty belong to user, PK on uid and FK on fid/sid

Comment: Yah exactly what i wants. now i understand.

Comment: @joynal, what is the relation between BirthDate and SendDate?

Comment: there is no relation between birthdate and senddate, this lines are auto generated by MySQL Workbench. relation i describe above.